# Is it possible to kill Vlad?

Tags: magicka

Is it possible to kill Vlad? I've tried many powerful beam spells and charged shots but he regenerates too quickly.

> This question specifically is in reference to whether Vlad can be killed *before* the fight in chapter 9.

If it can't be done solo, can it be done with 4 players?

Comment: Well, since he has assured us that he isn't a Vampire, I don't see any reason that he wouldn't be killable... I mean... it's not like he's Undead or anything, right? Right?

Comment: Oh, nice one you two. It's a good thing I chose not to submit my edit! At any rate, if this is something of a spoiler, don't use the spoilery words in your title and body but instead simply avoid mentioning the spoilery parts and use spoiler markup (it's a blockquote starting with `>!`) to hide the actual spoilery parts. Not playing this get (yet!), I don't know which parts should necessarily be hidden, though. But I imagine that the character name alone isn't the spoiler issue.

Comment: You don't have to worry too much about Community Wiki here, thethinman: only 2 edits actually contribute to the threshold because Mana's retag, LessPop's retag, and badp's rollback don't count.

Comment: @Grace Cool. I know I should honour the comm-wiki but I like my reputation.

Comment: Honestly, there's no need for this to turn Community Wiki - questions are exceptionally rare and unnecessary to community-own because it's rare that a question is community-asked. So, even without considering the reputation aspect, you don't need to have this converted. [I'm just reading your chat messages, that's all. ♪](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/471406#471406)

Comment: [A fitting name, I see](http://i.imgur.com/vVad3.png).

Comment: *After* the game, Vortex works just fine on him. Still doesn't prevent him from coming back :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot kill Vlad.

> until chapter 9

He usually sits there passive, until you move so far away from his spawn point, then he disappears. I think he's a ninja, because he disappears in a puff of smoke.

I've dispensed about 50,000 hitpoints on him in single/multiplayer mode. He bleeds a lot, he can be set on fire, frozen, but his health never changes.

As I said, he's probably a ninja. Right? <_<

Comment: Well, he's certainly not a Vampire. He's assured us of that!

Answer (score 4):

If you set him on fire, letting that do it's job, re-setting him on fire every second or so, the fire damage numbers will eventually raise to a point where his health regen fails, it's usually around when the damage hits about 5 million.

Comment: Can you prove this claim?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but the only way I've tried and found to work so far requires magic which is not found until after he turns incorporeal (Future Vlad). Four step plan:

1. Stand next to Vlad
2. Cast Summon Death (I also had Vlad on fire, but that doesn't do anything afaik).
3. Prepare teleport quickly, but only cast when the swing animation has started and Death can't retarget anymore (slow time before starting might help)
4. After teleporting out of the way of the scythe, turn around and see that Vlad has no proper death animation: He's standing there, frozen in the "cloak in front of teeth" pose he normally takes before smokepuffing, until he slowly sinks into the ground.

So yes, he can die, but it's a hassle, requires starting a second playthrough, botching it means you get decapitated, and he's a very sore loser about it all if you do succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Just... have you tried using vortex after you beat the game? Ice spikes, Arcane, Ice spikes, Shield, Ice spikes. So it's possible (combination QR|S|QR|E|QR for vortex, then hit space. I did it, it works)